# Objective-C Implement a timeout in non-blocking way

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, asynchronous, timeout

I am invoking an external async function that should invoke a callback once it completes.
However since the function is external, I do not control its implementation and I want to set a timeout for 5 seconds as an example and consider the operation of being timed out if the callback passed to that external async function wasn't invoked during those 5 seconds.

And the only way I currently found is to make the current thread sleep that actually blocks the thread.
Here is an example:
    `+(void)myFuncWithCompletion:(void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL))completion{
    BOOL timedOut = NO;
    BOOL __block finishedAsyncCall = NO;
    [someObj someAsyncMethod {
        // completion callback
        finishedAsyncCall  = YES;
        if (!timedOut) {
            completion(YES);
        }
    }];
    // This is the logic I want to fix. My goal is to make something similar but non-blocking.
    long timeoutInSeconds = 5;
    long startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    long currTime =  [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    while (!finishedAsyncCall && startTime + timeoutInSeconds > currTime) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0];
        currTime =  [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    }
    if (!finishedAsyncCall) {
        timedOut = YES;
        completion(NO);
    }
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `dispatch_after` instead of `-[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]`

```
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)); // 1 
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ // 2 
    if (!finishedAsyncCall ) {
        timedOut = YES;
        completion(NO);
    } 
});
```